# htaccess redirect with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

Current working url of acticles is following:

```
http://domain.com/index.php/news/{CATEGORY_ID}/{ARTICLE_ID}-{slug}.html
```

but I need this url to work also (via htaccess 301 redirect)

```
http://domain.com/index.php/news/article/view/{CATEGORY_ID}/{ARTICLE_ID}/
```

Please help to implement this redirect with parameters.
And this is the content of .htaccess file I have:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(ico|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|swf|flv)$ index.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/news/article/view/(.+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /index.php/news/%1/%2-all-the-same.html [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(ico|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|swf|flv)$ index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still it doesn't redirects and get this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'No route matched the request' in

Comment: Guess that URL causing mentioned error in the app log is in the final rewriten format (the original one)? When this aply, you should look at Zend framework routing configuration, maybe it is missing right -{slug} part of request. If not you can turn on RewriteLog and examine what exactly is going on while rewriting by adding two more directives like this to .htaccess: RewriteLog /path/to/logfile \newline RewriteLogLevel 3 . Loglevel 3 should be enough for analyzing this issue, of course you can raise the log level bit more, but it is then so verbose and thus unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule index.php/news/article/view/(.*)/(.*) index.php/news/$1/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the category and article IDs are numerical:

```
RewriteRule /index\.php/news/article/view/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ /index.php/news/$1/$2.html
```

If the IDs aren't numerical those portions should be replaced with `([^/]+)`.